# Difference between bayesian linear regression and regular linear regression independently fitting to mean and standard deviation

Tags: regression, bayesian, generalized-linear-model

As I understand, bayesian linear regression produces a posterior predictive distribution containing both the mean and standard deviation.

I've seen several blog posts showing the predicted mean is almost identical to the that of regular linear regression. Could we not use linear regression to predict the standard deviation of the target to achieve the same effect as the posterior predictive from bayesian linear regression?

I'm wondering what is the difference between the two approaches, and perhaps when one might be favoured over the other.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correct, but the difference is that one approach [produces a full distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/486878) that can then be summarized by two or more numbers (mean, variance/standard deviation), while the other only produces two point estimates.

Comment: Isn't that a distinction without a difference though? The two point estimates are two numbers as well, namely mean and variance / stdev. Conversely, those two numbers from the regular linear regression are two point estimates that can parameterise a distribution. I don't see a difference.

Comment: If no information (about the full distribution) is lost by summarizing it with two numbers (mean, variance) then there won't be much difference. But this would be the exception, not the rule. Not to mention the influence of priors that will [cause Bayesian point estimates to be slightly different](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/57257).