# Any examples of stochastic processes with continuous random variables and discrete time?

Tags: stochastic-processes

What are the examples of stochastic processes with continuous random variables and discrete time? Also, is Brownian motion defined on $t = [0,\infty[$?

Answer (score 1):

Three types of examples among many possibilities:

(1) Random walks (on the line, plane, etc.) with a uniformly distributed displacement left or right at each discrete step in time. The location at a given step is a continuous random variable.

(2) Many Gibbs samplers are discrete-time ergodic Markov chains with continuous values generated at each step. The chain is contrived so that the limiting distribution of the chain is the posterior distribution of a Bayesian model. By simulating the chain and looking at many simulated values near the end of a run, one can approximate the unknown posterior distribution. (One simple example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455129/trying-to-estimate-disease-prevalence-from-fragmentary-test-results).)

(3) Metropolis-Hastings approximations usually involve random walks in multi-dimensional spaces. At each step a random displacement in the space is made and a candidate value (often continuous) is generated, the candidate value
can be accepted or rejected according to some criterion. If rejected, the old value is replicated and a new displacement is tried. The result is
a simulated sample from a multivariate distribution. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) discussion.)